# Error function and ReLu in a CNN

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to get a better understanding of neural networks by trying to programm a Convolution Neural Network by myself.

So far, I'm going to make it pretty simple by not using max-pooling and using simple ReLu-activation. I'm aware of the disadvantages of this setup, but the point is not making the best image detector in the world.

Now, I'm stuck understanding the details of the error calculation, propagating it back and how it interplays with the used activation-function for calculating the new weights.

I read this document ([A Beginner's Guide To Understand CNN](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/)), but it doesn't help me understand much. The formula for calculating the error already confuses me.

[image]

This sum-function doesn't have defined start- and ending points, so i basically can't read it. Maybe you can simply provide me with the correct one?

After that, the author assumes a variable L that is just "that value" (i assume he means E_total?) and gives an example for how to define the new weight:

[image]

where W is the weights of a particular layer.

This confuses me, as i always stood under the impression the activation-function (ReLu in my case) played a role in how to calculate the new weight. Also, this seems to imply i simply use the error for all layers. Doesn't the error value i propagate back into the next layer somehow depends on what i calculated in the previous one?

Maybe all of this is just uncomplete and you can point me into the direction that helps me best for my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Theoretical questions about neural networks or other machine learning algorithms are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Consider looking for a question in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), and possibly asking there with a specific concern (asking just for pointers might be just as open-ended there as it is here).

Answer (score 0):

You do not backpropagate errors, but gradients. The activation function plays a role in caculating the new weight, depending on whether or not the weight in question is before or after said activation, and whether or not it is connected. If a weight `w` is after your non-linearity layer `f`, then the gradient `dL/dw` wont depend on `f`. But if `w` is before `f`, then, if they are connected, then `dL/dw` will depend on `f`. For example, suppose `w` is the weight vector of a fully connected layer, and assume that `f` directly follows this layer. Then,

```
dL/dw=(dL/df)*df/dw  //notations might change according to the shape 
                     //of the tensors/matrices/vectors you chose, but 
                     //this is just the chain rule
```

As for your cost function, it is correct. Many people write these formulas in this non-formal style so that you get the idea, but that you can adapt it to your own tensor shapes. By the way, this sort of MSE function is better suited to continous label spaces. You might want to use softmax or an svm loss for image classification (I'll come back to that). Anyway, as you requested a correct form for this function, here is an example. Imagine you have a neural network that predicts a vector field of some kind (like surface normals). Assume that it takes a 2d pixel `x_i` and predicts a 3d vector `v_i` for that pixel. Now, in your training data, `x_i` will already have a ground truth 3d vector (*i.e* label), that we'll call `y_i`. Then, your cost function will be (the index i runs on all data samples):

```
sum_i{(y_i-v_i)^t (y_i-vi)}=sum_i{||y_i-v_i||^2}
```

But as I said, this cost function works if the labels form a continuous space (here , `R^3`). This is also called a regression problem.

Here's an example if you are interested in (image) classification. I'll explain it with a softmax loss, the intuition for other losses is more or less similar. Assume we have `n` classes, and imagine that in your training set, for each data point `x_i`, you have a label `c_i` that indicates the correct class. Now, your neural network should produce scores for each possible label, that we'll note `s_1,..,s_n`. Let's note the score of the correct class of a training sample `x_i` as `s_{c_i}`. Now, if we use a softmax function, the intuition is to transform the scores into a probability distribution, and maximise the probability of the correct classes. That is , we maximse the function

```
sum_i { exp(s_{c_i}) / sum_j(exp(s_j))}
```

where `i` runs over all training samples, and `j=1,..n` on all class labels.

Finally, I don't think the guide you are reading is a good starting point. I recommend [this](http://cs231n.github.io/) excellent course instead (essentially the Andrew Karpathy parts at least).